# Dúvida com theme-color, mudar a cor do navegador

Tags: css, html5

Após acessar no celular, não observei que ele trocou a cor do navegador, nada mudou, usando o safari no ios ou Android, será que faltou alguma coisa?
Fiz a inclusão no meu head :

```
<!--mudar a cor do navegador -->
<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFFFFF" />
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#FFFFFF" />
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

Comment: tente colocar com aspas simples <meta name='theme-color' content='#FFFFFF' /> http://www.dicasparablogs.com.br/2016/03/mudar-cor-barra-enderecos-android.html

Comment: Agradeço, vou testar!

Comment: A solução do Douglar deu certo?

Comment: Não deu certo, veja http://rocasafari.com.br/

Comment: Um adendo sobre as informações a cima, se você estiver usando tema Dark no smartphone, o código não é habilitado.

Answer (score 1):

Por exemplo, para definir o plano de fundo para uma cor cor

Adicione abaixo **Meta property** ao seu código HTML em **HEAD**

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="theme-color" content="Seu Código Hexadecimal">
  ...
</head>
```

Examplo

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#444444">
  ...
</head>
```

Em abaixo da imagem, acabei de mencionar como o Chrome pegou sua propriedade de cor de tema

[image]

O Firefox OS, o Safari, o Internet Explorer e o Opera Coast permitem que você defina cores para elementos do navegador e até mesmo a plataforma usando metatags.

```
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#4285f4">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

### Estilo específico do Safari

Para mais detalhes [Documentação aqui](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

**Escondendo os componentes da interface do usuário do Safari**

Defina a meta-tag compatível com o aplicativo Apple-mobile-web-web para sim para ativar o modo autônomo. Por exemplo, o seguinte HTML exibe conteúdo da web usando o modo autônomo.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

**Alterando a aparência da barra de status**

Você pode alterar a aparência da barra de status padrão para preto ou preto-translúcido. Com preto-translúcido, a barra de status flutua em cima do conteúdo da tela cheia, em vez de pressioná-la. Isso dá ao layout maior altura, mas obstrui o topo. Aqui está o código necessário:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

Para mais informações sobre a aparência da barra de status, [veja apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW4)

Por exemplo:

**Screenshot usando preto-translúcido**

[image: Screenshot usando preto-translúcido]

**Screenshot usando preto**

[image: Screenshot usando preto]

Comment: Amigo, agradeço mais não deu certo, não sei o porque http://rocasafari.com.br/

Comment: @itasouza tenta outra cor em vez de branco